# C++ templates - Simple Point Class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a simple multi-dimensional Point class with templates (learning). I need two specializations Point2D and Point3D - here is what I have got so far to allow for constructors to initialize the Point directly like Point p (1, 2). Although this code compiles and works fine, what I don't like is the code repetition part in the specialization - I must be doing something wrong.

I am new to C++ / templates - any help is appreciated.

```
#ifndef POINT_H_
#define POINT_H_

template< typename T, int Dimensions = 2 >
class Point
{
public:
    typedef typename T value_type;

    Point() { std::fill(elements_, elements_+Dimensions, 0); }
    Point(const Point<T, Dimensions>& rhs) : elements_(rhs.elements_) {}
    ~Point() {}


    Point & operator=(const Point<T, Dimensions>& rhs) { return *this; }

    const Point operator+(const Point<T, Dimensions>& p)
    {
        Point<T, Dimensions> ret;

        for(int i = 0; i < Dimensions; i++)
        {
            ret[i] += elements_[i] + p[i];
        }

        return ret;
    }

    Point & operator+=( const Point<T, Dimensions>& p)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Dimensions; i++)
        {
            elements_[i] += p[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Point & operator-=( const Point<T, Dimensions> & p)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Dimensions; i++)
        {
            elements_[i] -= p[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T & operator[](const size_t index)
    {
        return elements_[index];
    }

private:
    T elements_[Dimensions];
};

template<typename T>
class Point< T, 2 >
{
public:
    Point(const T x, const T y)
    {
        elements_[0] = x;
        elements_[1] = y;
    }

    typedef typename T value_type;

    Point() { std::fill(elements_, elements_+Dimensions, 0); }
    Point(const Point<T, 2>& rhs) : elements_(rhs.elements_) {}
    ~Point() {}


    Point & operator=(const Point<T, 2>& rhs) { return *this; }

    const Point operator+(const Point<T, 2>& p)
    {
        Point<T, 2> ret;

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            ret[i] += elements_[i] + p[i];
        }

        return ret;
    }

    Point & operator+=( const Point<T, 2>& p)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            elements_[i] += p[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Point & operator-=( const Point<T, 2> & p)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            elements_[i] -= p[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T & operator[](const size_t index)
    {
        return elements_[index];
    }

private:
    T elements_[2];
};


template< typename T>
class Point< T, 3 >
{
public:

    Point(const T x, const T y, const T z)
    {
        elements_[0] = x;
        elements_[1] = y;
        elements_[2] = z;
    }

    typedef typename T value_type;

    Point() { std::fill(elements_, elements_+3, 0); }
    Point(const Point<T, 3>& rhs) : elements_(rhs.elements_) {}
    ~Point() {}


    Point & operator=(const Point<T, 3>& rhs) { return *this; }

    const Point operator+(const Point<T, 3>& p)
    {
        Point<T, 3> ret;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ret[i] += elements_[i] + p[i];
        }

        return ret;
    }

    Point & operator+=( const Point<T, 3>& p)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            elements_[i] += p[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Point & operator-=( const Point<T, 3> & p)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            elements_[i] -= p[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T & operator[](const size_t index)
    {
        return elements_[index];
    }

private:
    T elements_[3];
};

typedef Point< int, 2 > Point2Di;
typedef Point< int, 3 > Point3Di;


#endif //POINT_H_
```

Comment: I don't see any reason that you need to specialize this class at all.  It should all work with no specialization (aside from maybe a few minor tweaks).

Comment: Looks to me like you could put a lot of that repeated code into a common base class that your main class and it's specializations derive from.

Comment: @Chad, The only reason I want to specialize this is to add the constructor Point<T, 2>(T x, T y) as a convenience.

Comment: @jahhaj, As far as my current understanding goes, inheritence doesn't work well with templates. Can you suggest a sample code for one of the functions?

Comment: @user1588625 Inheritance works perfectly fine with templates.

Comment: Why not just provide named constructors [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Constructor] for the 2- and 3-dimensional case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just – simply – provide both a 2D and a 3D constructor in the main template.

There is no need to dally with base classes and other [Rube Goldberg solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg) here, because *there is no problem to be solved*: we're in template-land, where anything unused is simply unused.

Example:

```
#ifndef POINT_H_
#define POINT_H_

#include <array>            // std::array

#define STATIC_ASSERT( e ) static_assert( e, "!(" #e ")" )

template< typename T, int nDimensions = 2 >
class Point
{
private:
    std::array< T, nDimensions > elements_;

public:
    typedef T ValueType;

    T& operator[]( int const i )
    {
        return elements_[i];
    }

    T const& operator[]( int const i ) const
    {
        return elements_[i];
    }

    void operator+=( Point const& other )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < nDimensions; ++i )
        {
            elements_[i] += other.elements_[i];
        }
    }

    void operator-=( Point const& other )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < nDimensions; ++i )
        {
            elements_[i] -= other.elements_[i];
        }
    }

    friend Point operator+( Point const& a, Point const& b )
    {
        Point ret( a );

        ret += b;
        return ret;
    }

    friend Point operator-( Point const&a, Point const& b )
    {
        Point ret( a );

        ret -= b;
        return ret;
    }

    Point(): elements_() {}

    Point( int x, int y )
    {
        STATIC_ASSERT( nDimensions == 2 );
        elements_[0] = x;
        elements_[1] = y;
    }

    Point( int x, int y, int z )
    {
        STATIC_ASSERT( nDimensions == 3 );
        elements_[0] = x;
        elements_[1] = y;
        elements_[2] = z;
    }
};

typedef Point< int, 2 > Point2D;
typedef Point< int, 3 > Point3D;

#endif //POINT_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

wostream& operator<<( wostream& stream, Point3D const& point )
{
    return (stream << "(" << point[0] << ", " << point[1] << ", " << point[2] << ")");
}

int main()
{
    wcout << "starting" << endl;
    Point3D a( 1, 2, 3 );
    Point3D b( 4, 5, 6 );

    a += b;
    wcout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would just use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG for a better error message.

Comment: A side question: Any reason why you defined operator+= and operator-= as returning void instead of Point & and returning *this ?

Comment: @user1588625: I just see no reason to have more and possible less efficient code in order to support expressions with multiple side effects, which is ungood in modern software engineering. Support for multiple side effects made sense in C in the 1970's, when the programmer hand-crafted optimizations. Today that's the compiler's job, and our job is to write code that is clear and easy to understand for humans.

Comment: Nice idea to use the static assert, but this doesn't scale well to higher dimensions. I wonder if it is possible to implement some kind of variadic constructor solution.

Comment: I added a variadic template constructor example to my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: as of 2012 a standard C++ variadic conststructor is **non-portable**, as it's not supported by Visual C++ (which is the main compiler on the most used platform). Instead of that, for a larger number of dimensions add a constructor that takes an array, and conditionally, for C++11, one that takes an initialization list. That said, since the OP special-cased for 2 and 3 dimensions I doubt that the higher number of dimensions are relevant.

Comment: I keep forgetting about this VS limitation, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: How should retrieve Point3D.x, Point3D.y, and Point3D.z in this case? Thanks.

Comment: doesen't `operator+=` try to acces a private member variable from `Point const& other` in this example?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest having a class template similar to what you have shown:

```
template< typename T, int Dimensions>
class Point {
};
```

and then further `Point2D` and `Point3D` class templates that inherit from that:

```
template <typename T>
class Point2D : public Point<T,2>{
  // add X,Y constructor
};

template <typename T>
class Point3D : public Point<T,3>{
  // add X,Y, Z constructor
};
```

Another option, if you have C++11, is to add a variadic template constructor to the generic `Point` class template. This avoids inheritance entirely and is general for any number of dimensions:

```
template< typename T, unsigned int N>
class Point {
  template <typename ... Args>
  Point(const Args& ... args) : elements_{args...} {}
};
```

This would allow the following:

```
Point<int, 3> p3a(1,2,3); // OK, array values set to 1, 2, 3
Point<int, 3> p3b(1,2); // OK, array values set to 1, 2, 0
Point<int, 3> p3c(1,2,3,4); // compiler error! 
Point<double, 10> p10a(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); // OK
```

Comment: No need to make `elements_` protected is there?  `operator[]` has been provided to allow full access to the underlying storage in the base class.

Comment: @user1588625 I added an example that uses a variadic template constructor. This does away with the inheritance and is general for any number of dimensions.

Comment: @juanchopanza suppose now that in addition to constructors being added for `Point3D`, OP also wants to add some member functions such as: `Point3D::X()`, etc. Then, if OP wants to perform algebraic operations for `Point3D ptA` and `Point3D ptB`, we'd have: `ptC = ptA + ptB` return a `Point` instance of the base class since operators are defined in `Point` base class. therefore OP would be unable to call `ptC.GetX()`. is this right? The naive solution to this would be reimplement all the operator overloads in any class that derives from `Point`, but how would you avoid this code duplication?

Answer (score 1):

Like jahhaj says, move the common code into a base class template and inherit from it:

```
template<typename T, int Dimensions>
class PointBase {
    ...  // all existing code from Point
};

template<typename T, int Dimensions = 2>
class Point: public PointBase<T, Dimensions> {
    // empty
};

template<typename T>
class Point<T, 2>: public PointBase<T, 2> {
public:
    Point(T x, T y): PointBase<T, 2>() { // convenience constructor
       (*this)[0] = x;
       (*this)[1] = y;
    }
};
```

As an aside, C++11 variadic templates and initializer lists will remove any need to create convenience constructors by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out Luchian's answer, but it doesn't seem to work for providing new constructors in the specialization.

You can, however, use derivation to help provide types with different constructors.  Unfortunately, with this technique you have to redefine *all* of the constructors you want to expose.

As an aside, note that you don't need to repeat template parameters when refering to the current type within the definition of the templated type itself.

```
#ifndef POINT_H_ 
#define POINT_H_ 

template< typename T, int Dimensions = 2 > 
class Point 
{ 
public: 
    typedef typename T value_type; 

    Point() { std::fill(elements_, elements_+Dimensions, 0); } 
    Point(const Point& rhs) : elements_(rhs.elements_) {} 
    virtual ~Point() {} 


    Point & operator=(const Point& rhs) { return *this; } 

    Point operator+(const Point& p) 
    { 
        Point<T, Dimensions> ret; 

        for(int i = 0; i < Dimensions; i++) 
        { 
            ret[i] += elements_[i] + p[i]; 
        } 

        return ret; 
    } 

    Point & operator+=( const Point& p) 
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < Dimensions; i++) 
        { 
            elements_[i] += p[i]; 
        } 

        return *this; 
    } 

    Point & operator-=( const Point& p) 
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < Dimensions; i++) 
        { 
            elements_[i] -= p[i]; 
        } 

        return *this; 
    } 

    T & operator[](const size_t index) 
    { 
        return elements_[index]; 
    } 

private: 
    T elements_[Dimensions]; 
}; 


template<typename T>
class Point2D : public Point<T, 2>
{
public:

    Point2D()
    {
    }

    Point2D(const Point2D& rhs) : Point<T, 2>(rhs) 
    {
    }

    Point2D(const T x, const T y) 
    { 
        (*this)[0] = x; 
        (*this)[1] = y;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Point3D : public Point<T, 3>
{
public:

    Point3D()
    {
    }

    Point3D(const Point3D& rhs) : Point<T, 3>(rhs) 
    {
    }

    Point3D(const T x, const T y, const T z) 
    { 
        (*this)[0] = x; 
        (*this)[1] = y;
        (*this)[2] = z;
    }
};


typedef Point2D< int > Point2Di; 
typedef Point3D< int > Point3Di; 



#endif //POINT_H_
```

As a point of pedantry, You may wish to add a const index accessor in the base class as well:

```
    const T & operator[](const size_t index) const
    { 
        return elements_[index]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change count of input arguments of your constructor you have 2 ways:
1) Move all implementation to a base class and drive you class from it and then specialize drived class
2) Use a preprocessor command to repeat your constructor( for example with `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` ) and then disable invalid constructors using templates( `tr1::disable_if` or `boost::disabled_if` ).

First technic is very simple but for second one there is lot of documentation and help about `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` and 'disable_if`, if they do not help you let me know to send you a complete working code